# Precompiled HTML templates explain

Tags: html, parsing

I can not understand - precompiled HTML templates. Can anybody explain how this works in any language?

Answer (score 0):

The template is read into memory and converted to an optimised form for inserting data into.

As opposed to non-optimised ones which are read into memory on demand and the template language is parsed on demand.